# OpenFileDialog looks different in different projects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, openfiledialog

I'm trying a sample application from the book [Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours](http://www.informit.com/store/sams-teach-yourself-wpf-in-24-hours-9780672329852). I have typed pretty much the same code as the one that I have downloaded from their website.

There's a part where it uses the `OpenFileDialog` class. I'm developing in Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I think the system that the authors used was different.

Here are the snapshots of the `OpenFileDialog`s on my computer:

[image: OpenFileDialog in my project]
[image: OpenFileDialog in the downloaded project]

The first one is the snapshot of `OpenFileDialog` in my project, and the second one is of the downloaded project (again, they have almost exactly the same code).

I thought that it was because the downloaded version was compiled in another version of Windows, hence the difference. But it is the same, even when I compile it on my computer.

What causes the difference?

**Edit:** I've tried deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders in the solution directory, and rebuild the files. Still the windows are different.

Comment: Please don't read any book called  `Teach Yourself X in Y Hours`. None technology can **really** learn in 24 hours..

Comment: @SonerGonul Well, it sounds really low when someone talks about a book without even reading the foreword. Not all of the "in 24 hours" books are bad. It doesn't mean that you will learn everything about a given technology in 24 hours, it's just separated in 24 chapters that takes around an hour to finish. And it's name is not "Make yourself a complete expert in ... by reading this book in 24 hours". So "please", if you want to hate something  check it out first. P.S.: This specific book is really good for an introduction, in my opinion. And it has 4.5 stars on Amazon.

Comment: Sams "Teach yourself Java in 7 days" saved my university degree many years ago. I'm doing alright now. Just sayin'

Comment: When you recompile the downloaded version are you touching the code before you compile? (as in delete a character or semicolon somewhere and retype it and save again before building)

Comment: @Sayse I tried that now, still they look different.

Comment: hmm.. only other thing I would think of is that it is  targetting a different framework (right click on project > properties > application). All out of ideas sorry!

Comment: @Sayse Haha! That did the trick. I didn't realize that the other project was targeting .NET Framework 3.5, and my project was targeting 4.0. If you can write that as an answer, I'll take it as the accepted answer.

Comment: no worries :) must have just been an updated window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project is probably targetting a different framework

Right click on project > properties > application

Answer (score 1):

You have two different `OpenFileDialog` in different namespaces.

- `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`
- `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` : WinForms dialog you can also use in your WPF projects

Check which one your are using in your project.

Comment: Well I have already checked them, it's `Windows.Win32.OpenFileDialog`. As I've said, the code is almost exactly the same. And `OpenFileDialog` part is completely the same.

Comment: @hattenn Are both version running on the same computer?

Comment: Yeah, they are running on my computer.